# What may be the cause of oil in radiator

Tags: mazda-323f

i have a mazda 323 ZM/ZL engen,i found oil in the radiator after changing the head gasket.it once over heated.

Comment: When got the gasket changed? Did the radiator circuit got flushed afterwards?

Comment: Who did the head gasket change???

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a few things off the top of my head. The first would be a bad head gasket.  Since your engine overheated it's possible the head was warped which is preventing the gasket from sealing properly. There could be a crack in the head between the water and oil passages and also there could be a problem with the oil cooler.

Comment: @Moab Could you explain a little more?  I'm still somewhat of a novice and don't understand your comment.